# Parsing JSON nested arrays with JS

Tags: javascript, json

I've been going over various topics here with similar JSONs, but never the same and I'm still struggling with looping over the elements of an array.

I have the following JSON:

```
     {
     "person": 
     [
        {
            "id": "xyz",
            "attributes": 
            [
            {"attribute_name1": "value1"},
            {"attribute_name2": "value2"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "abc1",
            "attributes": 
            [
            {"attribute_name1": "value3"},
            {"attribute_name2": "value4"},
{"attribute_name3": "value77"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON is passed as a string beforehand.
Then I'm trying to list all the "persons" together with their IDs and list of attributes:

```
var data = '{"person":[ { "id": "xyz","attributes": [{"attribute_name1": "value1"},{"attribute_name2": "value2"}]},{"id": "abc1","attributes": [{"attribute_name1": "value3"},{"attribute_name2": "value4"},{"attribute_name3": "value77"}]}]}';

var json, i, j;
var json = data.toString();

json = JSON.parse(json);

for (i in json.person) {
  for (j in json.person[i].attributes) {
    var attribute_name = Object.keys(json.person[i].attributes[j]); // here because I won't know what are the actual names of those attributes
    console.log("Person's ID: " +json.person[i].id + " /// Person's Attribute name: " +attribute_name + " /// Person's Value: " +json.person[i].attributes[j]['attribute_name']);
    console.log("Person's Value: " +json.person[i].attributes[j]['attribute_name']); // this gives undefined
    console.log("Person's Value: " +json.person[i].attributes[j].attribute_name);    // this also gives undefined
  }
}
```

I'm happy to change the structure of the JSON if that will help in any way. Any hints on how to get the values of those attributes names if their name is not "fixed"?

Comment: can you explain what to actually want?

Comment: As mentioned, wanted to list all of the persons line by line with their IDs and attributes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Change JSON structure

```js
var person = [{id:1, name: 'John'},{id:2, name: 'Mary'}];
var attributes = [
 {person_id:1, name: 'attr_name', value: 'val1'},
  {person_id:2, name: 'attr_name2', value: 'val2'}
  ];
 
 // variant 1
 for (let attr of attributes) {
   if (attr.person_id === targetPersonId) { ... }
 }
 
 // variant 2
attributes.map(el => el.person_id === targetPersonId).forEach(... do something)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I cannot really split it, it must be one string of text that contains JSON code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet with your existing JSON structure.

```
const data = '{"person":[ { "id": "xyz","attributes": [{"attribute_name1": "value1"},{"attribute_name2": "value2"}]},{"id": "abc1","attributes": [{"attribute_name1": "value3"},{"attribute_name2": "value4"},{"attribute_name3": "value77"}]}]}';

const json = JSON.parse(data);

json.person.forEach((person) => {
  person.attributes.forEach((attribute) => {
    const properties = Object.keys(attribute);
    console.log(`Person's ID:`, person.id);
    properties.forEach((prop) => {
      console.log(`${prop} ${attribute[prop]}`);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however I struggle in understanding the short syntax here and not sure what is the ${prop} bit

Comment: These are string literals, you can read more about them on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). We are looping through `properties` with a `forEach` and `prop` is the current element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote from `json.person[i].attributes[j]['attribute_name']` i.e `json.person[i].attributes[j][attribute_name]`.

```
var data = '{"person":[ { "id": "xyz","attributes": [{"attribute_name1": "value1"},{"attribute_name2": "value2"}]},{"id": "abc1","attributes": [{"attribute_name1": "value3"},{"attribute_name2": "value4"},{"attribute_name3": "value77"}]}]}';
var json, i, j;

json = JSON.parse(data);
for (i in json.person) {
  for (j in json.person[i].attributes) {
    var attribute_name = Object.keys(json.person[i].attributes[j]);
    console.log("Person's ID: " +json.person[i].id + " /// Person's Attribute name: " + attribute_name + " /// Person's Value: " +json.person[i].attributes[j][attribute_name]);
    console.log("Person's Value: " +json.person[i].attributes[j][attribute_name]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but getting "invalid XML name" error, which is weird considering this has nothing to do with XML

Comment: @Valverde Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: When compiling the code it throws an "invalid XML name" error

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this, in case you want to get object with name / value from the json.

```
var object = {
     "person": 
     [
        {
            "id": "xyz",
            "attributes": 
            [
            {"attribute_name1": "value1"},
            {"attribute_name2": "value2"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "abc1",
            "attributes": 
            [
            {"attribute_name1": "value3"},
            {"attribute_name2": "value4"},
            {"attribute_name3": "value77"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}



var someobj = {};

function generate(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (key !== 'key' && key !== 'value') {
            obj[key].forEach(element => {
                someobj[element.id] = element.attributes;
                return someobj;
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
    var data = {
        person: [{
            id: "xyz", attributes: [{ attribute_name1: "value1" },
            { attribute_name2: "value2" }]
        },
        {
            id: "abc1", attributes: [{ attribute_name1: "value3" },
            { attribute_name2: "value4" }, { attribute_name3: "value77" }]
        }]
    };

    var json, i, j;
    //var json = data.toString();

    //json = JSON.parse(json);

    for (i in data.person) {
        console.log("Person's ID: " + data.person[i].id);
        for (j in data.person[i].attributes) {
            var attribute_name = Object.keys(data.person[i].attributes[j])[0]; // here because I won't know what are the actual names of those attributes
            console.log("Person's Value: " +attribute_name +"->" + data.person[i].attributes[j][attribute_name]); // this gives undefined
        }
    }
</script>
```